# Having problems making work samba on Ubuntu server 17.04

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

i´m just a noob in all of this OS, but i haven´t had any problems following the instructions given in some tutorials that explain how to make work samba on ubuntu server. That´s fine, I follow the tutorials and all perfect, but when I finish i always make the server be detected by my other machines (Mac OS and Windows). The problem comes when I try open one of this folders and it always says this: 
*"Windows cannot access UBUNTU\accesoseguro"
"You do not have permission to access \UBUNTU\accesoseguro. Contact your network administrator to request access"
The tutorial I´ve been mainly followed was this (https://ubunlog.com/como-instalar-y-configurar-samba-en/). I know it´s in spanish, but you will can see what´s explaining, if you can recommend me another more concrete, or a video...
Following this tutorial I make two folders, one which will be accesible by anyone called "Anonymous", which doesn´t need credentials to get into it and another one called "Compartido" which needs user & pass. But when I try to get inside one of them it appears the same message again.

Help please!

Comment: The exact error messages that you get are important.  If we could have the exact error messages it would help us to identify what is wrong with your configuration.  Some of your details don't fit.  You say in some generality the folder is unreachable, and you also say don't have permissions.  It's unclear how the permissions error can come to a resource that can't be reached.  It would help if we knew the exact step that is unreachable.  Fixing one might fix the other.  Also, try to use words that the system won't block or filter out.  That would assist in clarity also.

Comment: Sorry about that, ive changed it. The exact message that i get opening both folders on windows is: "Windows cannot access UBUNTU\accesoseguro" "You do not have permission to access \UBUNTU\accesoseguro. Contact your network administrator to request access." Thank you!